# termios.h defined value difference between sources

Tags: c, termios

I was astonished to find differences between macro definition of termios.h

On RHEL or Centos 7 I have the (also confusing octal) values

```
#define PARENB  0000400
#define PARODD  0001000
```

On other sources we see

```
#define PARENB      0x00001000  /* parity enable */
#define PARODD      0x00002000  /* odd parity, else even */
```

For PARENB 0x1000 = 4096 = 10000octal which is not 0000400

I thought it would be the same on all platforms/distributions (apart maybe for 32 bits/64bits distinction).

Why such difference ? Can we by mistake use one instead of the other ? is there an historical reason ?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of macros to be able to have different values on different platforms?

Comment: @Groo yes for sure. I thought this piece of software would be completely common even down to such definitions.

Comment: You work in terms of the macro names so that the numbers don’t matter. You should expect every implementation to use different numbers. The anomaly is when several implementations use the same number. That usually means there was history behind it; there were implementations that used numbers before it was standardized.